# Where to put properties file (in connection with maven assembly)

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, properties, maven-assembly-plugin

When I start my application within eclipse, it's no problem to have a properties file within the `src/main/resources` folder. When I then run `maven install`,  this properties file is put into a `config` folder with the help of maven assembly. So following issue:

While working in eclipse, I access the properties file simply with:

```
File propsFile = new File( "src/main/resources/settings.properties" );
```

After `maven install` I cannot reach this file anymore of course. But which workflow is the best, to reach the file during my eclipse development and after `maven install` without having it twice?!

My assembly structure after `maven install` looks like this:

```
application folder
    |----bin
        |----batch file to start my application
    |----lib
        |----my application jar
        |----other dependencies jars
    |----config
        |----settings.properties
```

Thanks a lot in advance already :)

Comment: How are you launching your application after it has been assembled? Through Maven? Through a simple system script?

Comment: Yes, using a .cmd file ...

Answer (score 0):

If you are launching your app through a script file, I'd suggest you to include into the classpath the folder where `settings.properties` is located at:

- In Eclipse you have to do nothing at all, because all the files from `src\main\resources` *are* actually copied right into the `target\classes` output directory, which is indeed at the heading of the classpath.
- And in your script file, you have only to pre-pend the `<application>\config` file at the beginning of the execution classpath.

But then you have to change the way you read resources from program: Replace using the `File` API by `ClassLoader.getResourceAsStream`:

```
InputStream input=getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("settings.properties");
Properties properties=new Properties(input);
```